# What is "origin" variable in Exception Object/Class of Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hi Im working on Ruby Script. 
Can any one tell me what is "origin" in Exception class/object and 
how to get/set the values of that variable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "origin"?

Comment: There is no such member, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Exception.html same in 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. Could you clarify your question, please ?

Comment: mu is too short and philippe, can u tell me any concept/variable named "origin" in RUby?

Comment: Can you provide some context? Maybe an error message and the surrounding code?

Comment: Please don't use txt speak on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception does not have any such method, nor do any core classes or classes in the standard library (as determined by running "ri origin" with Ruby 1.9.2).